# LVM Configuration possible?

Tags: raid, performance, lvm

I have hard discs D1 and D2 which are 140GB each and D3,D4 which are 600GB. I've been reading about the benefits of using LVM and I was thinking about the following configurations.

This one would be the one that makes sense to me cause I really want to keep OS/Data load in separated disks. But what has me thinking is that I'll only have 30-40GB left in the LV in case I need to expand home/usr/root. (Which is less likely to happen but you never know...)

```
|var,usr,home |   /data    |
 --------------------------
|   LVM Vol   |   EXT3/4   |
 --------------------------
|  HW RAID1   |  HW RAID1  |
 --------------------------
|  D1  |  D2  |  D3  | D4  |
```

Now, this crazy setup came to my mind and I dont know if its possible. Point of it is to create an LVM of both RAIDs making one huge VG of 740GB. This will give me a lot of flexibility in case I need to expand something.

```
| var,usr ,home, data ...  |
 --------------------------
|         LVM Vol          | 
 --------------------------
|    HW RAID1 |  HW RAID1  |
 --------------------------
|  D1  |  D2  |  D3  | D4  |
```

Is this possible? If it is, how can it affect performance compared to the first setup since Id like to keep OS/data load separated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the second configuration is possible.

LVM Volume Groups exist for exactly this reason: to put space from few Physical Volumes together.

Moreover, you can tell LVM to put your `/data` on D3/D4 RAID. Just do a

```
lvcreate -n data -L 600GB VolumeGroupName /dev/sdb1
```

So from performance point of view it won't change anything: data will be on big drives, all other volumes will be on small disks. Later you can use `pvmove` to move specific volumes (or parts of them) to other disks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I'd use is a hybrid of your first attempt:

```
|var,usr,home |   /data    |
 --------------------------
|LVM LV1,2,3  |   LVM LV0  |
 --------------------------
|   LVM VG    |   LVM VG   |
 --------------------------
|  HW RAID1   |  HW RAID1  |
 --------------------------
|  D1  |  D2  |  D3  | D4  |
```

That way, your 4 mount-points can be migrated between Volume Groups. 
That seems to make some degree of sense.

You'd then have

```
/var mounted as LVM LogicalVolume 1, formatted as EXT3/4
/home mounted as LVM LogicalVolume 3, formatted as EXT3/4
/usr mounted as LVM LogicalVolume 2, formatted as EXT3/4
/data mounted as LVM LogicalVolume 0, formatted as EXT3/4
```

Comment: Would I still be able to add lets say 10GB, from LV0 to LV1 without any problems?

Comment: It depends if you left some space free on either of the VGs to expand into.

Comment: The difference of your example from my second configuration is that I thought about 1 big VG instead of 2 like you suggested. Whats the benefit of this?

Comment: Keeps me sane. That's all.